How to get the client's IP address?
I want to get the IP address of the client. I have a server where I host my code in IIS.
string clientIpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();`

or
string clientIpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

or
private string GetClientIpAddress(HttpContext context)
{
    string ipAddress = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        ipAddress = context.Request.Headers["X-Real-IP"].FirstOrDefault();
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
    }

    return ipAddress ?? "unknown";
}

Whenever a request comes in, it should provide the client's IP address.
But every time, I am ending up getting the server system IP address, I mean the IIS system's IP address.
So how to get the IP of the calling client?

"or .net 8 C#"?  What would a "client" be in a non-ASP.NET context? A socket client? What? Please provide more information.

@ProgrammingLlama - given the reference to IIS, I am going to assume that it is Web application :)

your last way string ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString(); should get you client IP

Where you access this server? Directly from the current server or other client machine? Besides, do you have any proxy ?

@Felix me too, but the "or" is a bit confusing.

Unless you exist in a world where IPv6 is the norm and nobody is doing any NATting, the best you can hope for is an address, belonging to their ISP, and behind which any number of actual clients might exist. So, to what purpose were you planning to use the "client"s IP address? It's certainly not going to be a unique identifier for the client, as one example of a purpose it will not fulfil.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-8.0 You need the right configuration to trust any expected reverse proxy and parse headers properly.

As I said, your last way should be correct:
ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();

You may be passing incorrect HttpContext though. Try
ipAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();

instead
UPDATE: It looks like also an option that you tried. But it works for me all the time.
